# Issue with fmt.Println not consistent with thread printing order

Tags: go, goroutine

Consider the following code

```
package main

import (  
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    messages := make(chan bool)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var x = 1000

    wg.Add(runtime.NumCPU())
    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        go func(x int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            var i = 0
            for i < x {
                i += 1
                fmt.Println(i * i)
            }
            messages <- true
        }(x)
    }

    go func() {
        for i := range messages {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

And the following last couple of line output

```
980100
982081
984064
true
988036
990025
992016
994009
996004
998001
1000000
```

Since `message <- true` is always at the end of a for loop and

```
    for i := range messages {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
```

prints after the channel receive the message.

I expect `true` to be printed always at the end like

```
988036
990025
992016
994009
996004
998001
1000000
true
```

But I find that is only sometimes true, why is that?

Comment: You have multiple routines running concurrently, so while the order of operations within one routine will be deterministic, the order of operations across multiple routines is not.

Comment: @Adrian but shouldn't the last goroutine that finishes have the last true printed in the last line?

Comment: Can you change the channel to accept an int and print that? I wonder if it's just the `fmt.Print` that is re ordering the *strings that has to print (*I avoided the word `messages` or `variables` to avoid confusion with the messages in your code..)

Comment: @Jal, about your last comment. You can think that the second goroutine will take 1day on being executed, while the first will be executed immediately. (yes, those are an extreme difference of time, but helps to make a mental diagram). So, you know that the first goroutine will take some seconds, but the second goroutine will be executed in the futureeeeeee. What or who is waiting for the second goroutine to finish before `main()` ends?

Comment: ah everything make sense now, thankx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is:

1. Start a number of goroutines, equal to the number of CPUs on your system.
2. Start one additional goroutine, which reads and prints the values from the `messages` channel.
3. Wait for the goroutines from #1 to terminate
4. Exit

Because you're only waiting for the first batch of goroutines to terminate, there is no guarantee that all (or even any) of the `messages` values will be printed before the program terminates.

Comment: Just complementing this answer; @Jal you can just wait for the channel. If you know that you will pass only one message at the end of the loop you can do this; https://play.golang.org/p/82jQCyXCL74